# Need to implement k means clustering on hot encoded dataset using SQL

Tags: mysql, k-means

Dataset looks like, it is one hot encoded dataset and i want to do kmeans clustering on it, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Don't think you can do it using MySQL alone. You will need to use some kind of server-side language to do it, like PHP or Python, among many others. SQL is only good for retrieving data and doing basic grouping, arithmetic, and manipulation.

Comment: I need to do it using query only, this is the case